# Obtaining PID of command earlier in Pipeline

Tags: bash, pipe, pid

I'm writing a bash script to use `inotifywait` to monitor a directory and kick off actions when changes are detected. Something like:

```
inotifywait -m ... | while read f; do something; done
```

Since `inotifywait` doesn't terminate by itself, this script will not halt.

So my plan was to get the PID of the inotifywait process, save it to a file and have a different process kill it later, say like:

```
inotifywait -m ... | { echo ??PID?? > pid-file; while ... }
```

But I don't know how to get the PID.  Is there a simple way to achieve this?  Another way is just to save the PID of the shell-script `$$` to the file and kill the entire shell-script but I wanted to do some cleanup after the while loop.

I have tried using `coproc` and I think it will work but it seems like more complication than necessary.

Comment: You could use something like this `
ps -ef | grep processName | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
`

Comment: @Kiwy - instead of that mess just do a `pgrep inotifywait`. That will give you the PID,to kill, `pkill inotifwait`.

Comment: @slm depending of your system you will not have pgrep and pkill while grep and ps while almost be present. You're welcome

Comment: @Kiwy - doubtful, those tools are pretty ubiquitous. Also you do not need to do a `grep -v grep`, instead `ps -ef | grep [p]rocessname...` would do the same.

Comment: @Kiwy - yes and given we're talking about `inotifywait` I believe that's only a Linux technology or at the very least not present on AIX. I'm not trying to be insulting and if I did I apologize, just trying to be concise.

Comment: @slm, although your method looks cleaner, it is possible that `pgrep` won't do the job. Refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/157075/why-does-ps-aux-grep-x-give-better-results-than-pgrep-x - `pgrep` only looks at the first 15 characters and so if `inotifywait` is listed as `/usr/local/bin/inotifywait` for example, `pgrep` won't work while Kiwy's method will work.

Comment: @DavidsonChua - yes you can use the `-f` switch if you need to match against more of the executables name.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. Perhaps you would like to edit your commands in your earlier comment to `pgrep -f inotifywait`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652680/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-that-is-piped-to-another-process-in-bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a pipeline, all processes are started *concurrently*, there's not one that is *earlier* than the others.

You could do:

```
(echo "$BASHPID" > pid-file; exec inotifywait -m ...) | while IFS= read -r...
```

Or portably:

```
sh -c 'echo "$$" > pid-file; exec inotifywait -m ...' | while IFS= read -r...
```

Also note that when the subshell that runs the `while` loop terminates, `inotifywait` would be killed automatically the next time it writes something to stdout.

Answer (score 4):

If you need the process ID in the loop, print it first.

```
sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec inotifywait -m ...' | {
  read inotifywait_pid
  while IFS= read -r f; do
    …
    if …; then kill "$inotifywait_pid"; break;
  done
}
```

Comment: beautifully simple.

Answer (score 1):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048493/519015) seems applicable:

```
inotifywait -m file > >(while read f; do echo f; done) &
```