# Determining if neighbouring process in pipeline has execve'd

Tags: shell, pipe, proc, exec

I have a sequence of processes in a pipeline:

```
cat haystack | grep needle | my_process | less
```

My understanding is that the shell forks and runs execve for each command concurrently.

In my_process, how could I determine if grep and less have fully started (execve'd), assuming I have already determined their PIDs?

Comment: What is rhat supposed to be good for?

Comment: check for EOF on stdin and trap SIGPIPE for stdout.  and, in bash at least, if you want to know the exit status of each command in the most-recently executed pipeline, examine the PIPESTATUS array.

Comment: @HaukeLaging for establishing a side channel to pipes in a way that is backwards compatible with other processes

Comment: And what is this side-channel actually for?  It cannot be for the stated purpose, because overlaying a new process image file is not the same point as the point that a program actually starts doing its main work, let alone the (potentially several) points at which a program like `less` sets up and tears down its full-screen TUI.

Comment: @JdeBP I need it to determine when the neighbouring process(es) are also an instance of my_process. I don't know how many processes there will be beforehand and cannot modify the shell. I was doing this by checking /proc/<pid>/exe however there are problems when the neighbour is between fork and execve. I was going to use the answer to wait until the execve had completed since this would indicate that /proc/<pid>/exe is valid; it no longer points to the shell executable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, on Linux, you could check `/proc/PID/exe`:

```
(p=$BASHPID; /bin/ls -l /proc/$p/exe; exec /bin/ls -l /proc/$p/exe)
... 0 Jan 17 10:34 /proc/17816/exe -> /bin/bash
... 0 Jan 17 10:34 /proc/17816/exe -> /bin/ls
```

But I can't really see what that's good for, the shell won't read/write to the pipe before the `exec`, so the pipeline works seamlessly even if there is a small window of time before the `exec`. And really, it's a *small* window of time, I wouldn't be surprised if the `exec` had already happened by the time you can even get there to check what program is running.

Comment: That is the boring part. The interesting one is finding the PIDs of your "pipeline neighbours"... I remember this has been answered before but I doubt I would find the question.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, yeah, I found these: [Obtaining PID of command earlier in Pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103472/obtaining-pid-of-command-earlier-in-pipeline) and [Get PID of any command in backgrounded piped sequence of commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156140/get-pid-of-any-command-in-backgrounded-piped-sequence-of-commands). They involve saving the PIDs while starting the processes, or scanning through `/proc` for the pipes, neither of which is very satisfying. If there was any practical use for the PIDs, the shell could export the data directly.

Comment: @HaukeLaging [How can I get more info on open pipes show in /proc in Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48330/how-can-i-get-more-info-on-open-pipes-show-in-proc-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

This is what inheriting open file descriptors is for.

Make a FIFO.  Open a close-on-exec write-only file descriptor to it in the parent shell.  All of the `fork()`ed children will inherit it, and then close it when they `execve()`.  Open a read-only file descriptor to it in the process that needs to detect the `execve()`, or have that process inherit an already-open read-only file descriptor.  When the write-only ends are closed by the `execve()`, the read-only end will return EOF.

For detecting individual `execve()`s, generalize to multiple FIFOs.  Indeed, at that point you can not bother with FIFOs and *just use a second set of pipes*, with their write file descriptors set to close-on-exec.

Since you have not explained what this is actually *for*, working out how to build this into what you are actually trying to do is your task alone.

Answer (score 1):

Only Linux  and with `zsh`,

```
$ autoload zsh/stat
$ (zstat +link /proc/*/fd/0(e'{[[ $REPLY -ef /proc/self/fd/1 ]] &&
    reply=$REPLY:h:h/exe}')) | cat
/bin/cat
```

That gives you the path of the executable of process(es) that have the same pipe as that subshell's stdout open on their stdin. So above, at that point, `cat` had already been executed.